# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load property editor when farming geronimo using Deployment version 3.0.1

Tags: java, apache, geronimo

I'm trying to farm geronimo using deployment according to https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/GMOxDOC22/Farming+using+Deployment

1) install the required modules on both servers and started the modules.

2) updated the var\config\config.xml with following farming config info:

```
<gbean name="org.apache.geronimo.configs/farming/3.0.1/car?ServiceModule=org.apache.geronimo.configs/farming/3.0.1/car,j2eeType=NodeInfo,name=prodApp2"  gbeanInfo="org.apache.geronimo.farm.config.BasicNodeInfo">
<attribute name="name">prodApp2</attribute>
<attribute propertyEditor="org.apache.geronimo.farm.config.BasicExtendedJMXConnectorInfoEditor" name="extendedJMXConnectorInfo">
<ns:javabean class="org.apache.geronimo.farm.config.BasicExtendedJMXConnectorInfo"
xmlns:ns4="http://geronimo.apache.org/xml/ns/attributes-1.2"
xmlns:ns="http://geronimo.apache.org/xml/ns/deployment/javabean-1.0"
xmlns="">
<ns:property name="username">system</ns:property>
<ns:property name="password">manager</ns:property>
<ns:property name="protocol">rmi</ns:property>
<ns:property name="host">10.9.90.102</ns:property>
<ns:property name="port">1100</ns:property>
<ns:property name="urlPath">JMXConnector</ns:property>
<ns:property name="local">false</ns:property>
</ns:javabean>
</attribute>
</gbean>
```

3) Started server and got the exception.

```
    2014-05-28 06:15:00,828 ERROR [GBeanInstanceState] Error while starting; GBean is now in the FAILED state: abstractName="org.apache.geronimo.configs/farming/3.0.1/car?configurationName=org.apache.geronimo.configs/farming/3.0.1/car"
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load property editor [org.apache.geronimo.farm.config.BasicExtendedJMXConnectorInfoEditor]
    at org.apache.geronimo.system.configuration.GBeanOverride.loadPropertyEditor(GBeanOverride.java:443)
    at org.apache.geronimo.system.configuration.GBeanOverride.getValue(GBeanOverride.java:419)
    at org.apache.geronimo.system.configuration.GBeanOverride.applyOverrides(GBeanOverride.java:368)
    at org.apache.geronimo.system.configuration.LocalAttributeManager.setAttributes(LocalAttributeManager.java:234)
    at org.apache.geronimo.system.configuration.LocalAttributeManager.applyOverrides(LocalAttributeManager.java:203)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.config.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:218)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor35.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:534)
    at org.apache.xbean.recipe.ReflectionUtil$ConstructorFactory.create(ReflectionUtil.java:958)
    at org.apache.xbean.recipe.ObjectRecipe.internalCreate(ObjectRecipe.java:276)
    at org.apache.xbean.recipe.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:96)
    at org.apache.xbean.recipe.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:61)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstance.createInstance(GBeanInstance.java:958)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstanceState.attemptFullStart(GBeanInstanceState.java:271)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstanceState.start(GBeanInstanceState.java:105)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstance.start(GBeanInstance.java:555)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.basic.BasicKernel.startGBean(BasicKernel.java:368)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.config.KernelConfigurationManager.load(KernelConfigurationManager.java:191)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.config.SimpleConfigurationManager.loadConfiguration(SimpleConfigurationManager.java:358)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.config.SimpleConfigurationManager.loadConfiguration(SimpleConfigurationManager.java:331)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.osgi.ConfigurationActivator.start(ConfigurationActivator.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:299)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.config.SimpleConfigurationManager.loadConfiguration(SimpleConfigurationManager.java:311)
    at org.apache.geronimo.system.main.EmbeddedDaemon.doStartup(EmbeddedDaemon.java:234)
    at org.apache.geronimo.system.main.EmbeddedDaemon.execute(EmbeddedDaemon.java:94)
    at org.apache.geronimo.system.osgi.BootActivator$1.execute(BootActivator.java:107)
    at org.apache.geronimo.main.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:88)
    at org.apache.geronimo.main.Bootstrapper.execute(Bootstrapper.java:61)
    at org.apache.geronimo.cli.AbstractCLI.executeMain(AbstractCLI.java:65)
    at org.apache.geronimo.cli.daemon.DaemonCLI.main(DaemonCLI.java:33)
    Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: org.apache.geronimo.farm.config.BasicExtendedJMXConnectorInfoEditor
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:359)
    at org.apache.geronimo.system.configuration.GBeanOverride.loadPropertyEditor(GBeanOverride.java:441)
    ... 35 more
```

Is there any solution or any other approach available for farming configuration in geronimo?